# Unsupported monitor resolution after upgrade from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, resolution, monitor

Upgraded my server from **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS** to **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** as per update manager suggestion. I was running **1920 X 1080** under 10.04.  Now the video card is set outside the capabilities of the monitor.  Have no **Xorg.conf** file. Where can one find documentation of the boot process and files.  Don't mind doing the research, but the forum seem to be a circular treadmill.

Computer Specification: ASUS motherboard with an ATI Rage 128 video card driving a Dell HD widescreen monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Current X11 can start without `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and usually works well with DVI/LCD monitor. However monitor with vga cable or older monitor may still need `xorg.conf`.

After upgrade, your old xorg.conf maybe moved to

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.dist-upgrade-20130108
```

Copy it back to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and restart `lightdm`.

If they are completely missing, you many have to recreate your `xorg.conf`.

Comment: I will check into this.  One thing that I noticed was that, immediately after the upgrade, Ubunut thought it was running in Laptop display mode.  Where do these display modes come from?

Comment: X11 auto detect. You can see the flow/log at /var/log/Xorg.log.0